# Best way to implement Heroku application creation workflow on AWS

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, devops

I have an app that is a school management app  built using Laravel currently hosted on Heroku. Each app connects to the **same github repo**  and each app connects to it's own database (each school has it's own database), the Database name for each app is in the environment variable of the app and each school has it's own subdomain.
The workflow of the setting up is as follows.

1. I create an app for each school then connect that app to the main Github repo & branch. I then add the database name in the environment variable section for that app.
2. For custom domain, I generate a DNS nameserver from Heroku and then go to CloudFlare and create a CNAME record for that DNS nameserver.

I would like to replicate the same workflow (or better) in AWS.

I have little to no experience in DevOps, how would I go about it.

I did try to research  I found the following ways to go about it.

1. Use AWS Elastic Beanstalk and create apps there and connect to GitHub.
2. Use AWS ECS and create containers, each school app having it's container where there will be the specific DB configurations for that school
3. Use EC2 each school having it's own EC2 instance.

I want a more efficient method (both cost and devOps efficiency), where I will be able to just push to GitHub once and all that schools will get the update. Since all the schools read from the same repo but connect to different databases (but same DB server) and each school has it's own subdomain.

How can I best do this on AWS. I would greatly appreciate advice on how to best go about it. I will do it, I just need a headsup or advice on how to go about it.

Thank you